# Can't access array index in assembly x86

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, nasm

I'm trying to do in assembly the equivalent to:

```js
const array = ["ola", "mundo"]

for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
  console.log(array[i])
}
```

```
global main

section .data
        newline db 0xa
        array db "ola","mundo"
        arrayLength equ $ - array

section .text

main:
        mov ecx, 0

beginLoop:
        cmp ecx, arrayLength
        je exit

        mov r8d, ecx
        push ecx

        mov eax, 4
        mov ebx, 1
        mov ecx, array+r8d
        mov edx, arrayLength
        int 0x80

        mov eax, 4
        mov ebx, 1
        mov ecx, newline
        mov edx, 1
        int 0x80

        pop ecx
        inc ecx
        jmp beginLoop

exit:
        mov eax, 1
        mov ebx, 0
        int 0x80
```

But when I compile it, it throws an error whenever I use the register `r8d` to access the index:

> nasm -f elf64 -o array.o array.asm
> array.asm:22: error: invalid operand type

The line 22 is `mov ecx, array+r8d`.

Comment: You should use `lea` not `mov`. Not enough to fix your code though. For starters, `array db "ola","mundo"` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: You have to decide what kind of array you want — array of pointers to strings, or array of fixed-sized strings of equal length.

Comment: @Jester i tried with lea but it also didn't work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but when I compile it, it throws an error whenever I use the register `r8d` to access the index:

NASM can't load the address via `mov ecx, array+r8d` because the `r8d` component is not an immediate value, it's a register whose value is only available at runtime. You could use LEA and write `lea rcx, [array + r8]`. Use the whole qword register in an addressing mode.

> ```
> array db "ola","mundo"
> ```

There's no way for your program to know where one array element ends and where the next array element begins. All your program 'sees' is an 8-character string of characters "olamundo".
One solution could be using zero-termination like in `array db "ola", 0, "mundo", 0`. Another solution could do with strings of equal size using a filler like in `array db "ola     ", "mundo   "`. And yet another solution could be prefixing the array elements with a byte that holds a length indication:

```
array db 3, "ola", 5, "mundo"
arrayLength equ $ - array
```

A first draft:

```
main:
  mov   rsi, array
  mov   ebx, 1
.Loop:
  movzx edx, byte [rsi]  ; Load RDX with length byte
  inc   rsi              ; Make RSI point at current text string
  mov   rcx, rsi
  add   rsi, rdx         ; Now RSI points at next array element
  mov   eax, 4
  int   0x80
  mov   edx, 1
  mov   rcx, newline
  mov   eax, 4
  int   0x80
  cmp   rsi, array + arrayLength
  jb    .Loop
```